# How do I combine these two AWS-IAM policies to allow certain actions to only certain directories?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

The premise is this; I want groups that give permissions to Actions, and groups that permissions to AWS resources. By adding users to multiple groups, I should be able to control permissions to resources per user. However, when implementing the policies below, access to S3 buckets are not properly restricted;

```
 {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
            "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
            "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::*/*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
]
}


{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::path/to/my/bucket/directory",
                "arn:aws:s3:::path/to/my/bucket/directory/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Permissions apply to actions on resources. They can't be controlled independently. Perhaps you can elaborate on an example or two of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hmm... trying to think of a better way to express it. If I create two groups; GA, and GB each with policies that I've shown in the question, then I create a user A, and add them to GA and GB, I want user-A to now be able to perform the 5-actions shown only on the S3 directory given.

Comment: Perhaps a matrix of group policies for the relevant role/bucket pairs e.g. admin-sales, auditor-sales, viewer-sales, admin-cms, viewer-cms. Each group policy indicates both the permissions and the bucket(s). Each user can be a member of one or more groups (e.g. a member of both admin-sales and admin-cms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user is in multiple groups, all groups' statements (both `Allow` and `Deny`) are merged. As always, in the resulting policy `Deny` statements take precedence over `Allow`.

In your case, the resulting policy would allow:

1. The five actions on all S3 resources, AND
2. Any action on `path/to/my/bucket/directory` and its children.

In other words, combining Allow-only policies can only result in a more permissive policy, not less.

You could try some dirty hacks denying NotAction's on NotResource's, but it's impossible to override deny statements should you later want to allow the users something else.

Answer (score 0):

As previously noted, you cannot accomplish this using IAM Groups and identity-based permission policies.  However, there are other ways to accomplish something similar.

For instance, if you can set up your application so that the first permission statement is in an identity-based permission policy (i.e., attached directly to the User or Role or indirectly through a Group) and that the second is in a privilege boundary or session policy, then you'd have what you want: privilege boundaries and session policies cannot grant permissions but if one is in place, then any action attempted must be allowed by *both* the caller's identity-based permission policies and any applicable privilege boundaries and session policies.  (Note that there are some special cases involving resource-based permission policies where privilege boundaries and session policies don't apply.)